# Printing select sections of an array list if a condition is met

Tags: java, arraylist, printing

I'm writing a program that allows the user to check dogs into a kennel and I'm having some trouble printing all of the dogs that like bones (one of the criteria in the arraylist when you add a dog). I'm trying to print out just the name when you select the option "print all dogs who like bones" from the main console menu, but it's printing out all information from the array list.

Here's the current code:

```
private void printDogsWithBones() {

    Dog[] dogsWithBones = kennel.obtainDogsWhoLikeBones();
    System.out.println("Dogs with bones: ");

    for (Dog d: dogsWithBones){
        System.out.println(d);
    }   
}

public Dog[] obtainDogsWhoLikeBones() {    
    // TODO
    // Prints "null" if a dog is in the array that doesn't like bones.

    Dog[] tempResult = new Dog[dogs.size()];
    // Sets the int tempResult to -1 to allow for scanning through the array from position 0, making sure every dog is accounted for.
    int tempCount = -1;

    // For each loop to scan through the array and check for each dog that likes bones
    for (Dog t : dogs){
        // Adds 1 to tempCount to enable efficient and functional scanning through the array
        tempCount++;
        // Adds the animal from the array to the temp Array which will then be printed back in KennelDemo
        if(t.getLikesBones() == true){
            tempResult[tempCount] = t;
        }
    }
    return tempResult;
}
```

Another issue I'm having is that if the dog doesn't like bones, it prints out "null" instead of nothing at all.

Here's what the console prints out when the method is ran:

```
1 -  add a new Dog 
2 -  set up Kennel name
3 -  print all dogs who like bones
4 -  search for a dog
5 -  remove a dog
6 -  set kennel capacity
q - Quit
What would you like to do:
3
Dogs with bones: 
null
Dog name:RoverLikes Bones?:trueOriginal Owner:[David         98765]Favfood:NipplesFoodPerDay:3
Dog name:IzzyLikes Bones?:trueOriginal Owner:[Jay 123456789]Favfood:CurryFoodPerDay:3
```

Thanks in advance everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're skipping array indexes in your tempResult array where the dog doesn't like bones. Even if the dog doesn't like bones, you're increasing tempCount and so the current value will be skipped. To fix, move the tempCount increment inside the if statement.

```
if(t.getLikesBones() == true){
    tempCount++;
    tempResult[tempCount] = t;
}
```

Also, as t.getLikesBones() will evaluate to true, you don't need == true. You could also use a prefix increment on your array index, but this could decrease readability.

```
if(t.getLikesBones()){
    tempResult[++tempCount] = t;
}
```

Using an array when you don't know it's size on creation generally suggests you should be using a list. This will dynamically resize itself for you. If you then want to convert back to an array that's fine, but maybe lists instead of arrays would be a better fit for your whole application

```
public Dog[] obtainDogsWhoLikeBones() {    

    // Initialise dogsWhoLikeBones list
    ArrayList<Dog> dogsWhoLikeBones = new ArrayList<Dog>();

    // Iterate through dogs
    for (Dog dog : dogs){
        if(dog.getLikesBones()){
            // If a dog likes bones, add them to the list
            dogsWhoLikeBones.add(dog);
        }
    }

    // Get size of list to set the size of the return array
    int listSize = dogsWhoLikeBones.size();

    // Convert dogs list back to an array
    return dogsWhoLikeBones.toArray(new Dog[listSize]);
}
```

To print out the name of the dog rather than java's attempt to turn your object into a string, in your printing for loop you need to get it's name. Do you have an accessor for this in your dog class (e.g getName)? If so you can do:

```
for (Dog d: dogsWithBones){
    System.out.println(d.getName());
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this result in the tempCount never increasing if the value returned false for likeBones? 

thanks for your answer!

Comment: just edited and ran the code, it's now printing everything in the array as before but printing "null" at the bottom rather than at the start of the console message.

Comment: @JayGould Yep, that's the idea. You're only using tempCount to access tempResult, so you only wan't to increment it when a new item has been insterted. You're now getting nulls because the array of dogs is bigger than the array of dogs that like bones, so you have two options, either resize the array or use a list instead. If you don't know how big your array is going to be when you create it then a list is normally a better idea. Are lists an option? If so I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: There aren't any limits to what I can use at the moment, it's more a case of printing out the correct data rather than the method used. In honesty I could set up a huge scan method for it all and do it that way but I'd rather have it done efficiently. Would you mind explaining the list method?

Comment: Also I'm looking to only print out the names of the dogs rather than all of the info in the array correlating to the dog, is that possible?

Comment: @JayGould no worries, any more questions let me know!